# Mixed parameterization of sample from normal distribution

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, exponential-family, parameterization

I am studying exponential families and mixed parameterizations. Now, I am told that
$$
\mathbf{\theta} = \begin{bmatrix}\mu\\ -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\end{bmatrix}
$$
is the parameter in a variation-independent mixed parameterization for a sample of $i=1,\dots,n$ observations, sampled from $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ independently, with $\mu$ and $\sigma$ unknown but I have not been able to derive this for myself.

The joint distribution of the samples is given by
$$
f(\mathbf{x}|\mu,\sigma^2) = 
(2\pi \sigma^2)^{-n/2} \exp \left[ -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \left( x_i^2 - 2x_i\mu + \mu^2\right) \right].
$$
I want to rewrite this density function so that it takes the form
$$
a(\mathbf{\theta})h(\mathbf{x})\exp[\mathbf{\theta}^\intercal t\mathbf({x})]
$$
and this is where I am stuck. I can see that 
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(\mathbf{x}|\mu,\sigma^2) &= 
(2\pi \sigma^2)^{-n/2} \exp \left[ -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \left( x_i^2 - 2x_i\mu + \mu^2\right) \right] \\
&= (2\pi \sigma^2)^{-n/2} 
\exp \left[ -\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{2\sigma^2}   + \frac{\mu\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{\sigma^2} \right] \exp \left[ \frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2} \right] \\
\end{aligned},
$$
but this only leads me to the normal canonical parameterization with
$$
\mathbf{\theta} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2} \\ -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\end{bmatrix}\quad t(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{bmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \\ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is not what I need.

Can anybody give me a hint as to how to proceed to uncover the mixed parameterization?

*Note: This is related to a course assignment, so please avoid complete solutions for the time being, thank you.*

Comment: Please add `self-study` as a tag to ensure someone does not provide a full resolution. And please recall the definition of a mixed parameterisation. I have never heard the term before.

Comment: It seems to me at the last line you have derived *exactly* what you need.  Simply give $\mu/\sigma^2$ a new name--let's call it $\theta_1$--and observe that now $$\theta = \pmatrix{\theta_1 \\ -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}}$$ is in precisely the form you begin your question with.

Comment: thanks, @whuber, but the intention is to have variantion independent parameter components, so I need $\theta_1$ to be free of $\sigma^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by free? Both $\mu$ and $\mu/\sigma^2$ are free to vary in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Could you explain what it might mean for $\theta_1$ "to be free of" $\sigma^2$? It explicitly has nothing to do with $\sigma^2.$  I'm guessing here, but it sounds like you are aiming for two incompatible results: in some unstated way, you want the components of $\theta$ to have some specified relationship with the first two moments of the distribution.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, they are both free to vary. Nevertheless, I still need the parameterization that I described in the question. The reason is not instrumental to this problem, but is that I want to construct a conditional maximum likelihood estimator (conditional on $\mu$). I believe that the solution probably involves factoring out something that is $\chi^2$ (or proportinal thereof), but I'm not there yet.